Magento 1 when I clear the configuration cache in admin panel, and everything goes to a 404 error
If I clear all the other caches, the issue does not occur.
The problem happens only when I clear the configuration cache, and everything goes to a 404 error.
error Screenshot : https://i.imgur.com/kEzF46x.png (config_errors.log file)

Can you check if the permissions are correct?  I would start from that part. Is the problem on Server or on your local machine.
We might need more information to help you out.

The var/cache directory currently has permissions set to 777. if your'e talking about any other permisions then please specify which permissions need to be provided.
Also, the problem appears in server not in our local system.

I think you might have 775  drwxrwsr-x instead of 777 and then check owners also.

i change the permissions 775 and owner but still getting same error

Can you find anything in logs? maybe try disabling cache?
php shell/indexer.php reindexall

The files dont exist.
cache.xml files are not part of Magento CE. (maybe they existed in EE).
Pleasy check installed extensions.
